# how to Issue for cypress installation problem

Tags: node.js, reactjs, testing, cypress, end-to-end

During installation, when I try to use it, I encounter the following errors, and I deleted and reinstalled it many times
[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried `npx cypress open`?

Comment: @agoff Yes, if you see the picture, I used the same recipe

Comment: Have you installed prior to opening with `npm install`?

Comment: @jjhelguero yes I used npm install cypress --save-dev

Answer (score 0):

have you tried running `node_modules/.bin/cypress open`? you should run this command when you run cypress for the first time so it will create and validate its location in the path that appears in the error.